# Android Java: Convert else-if to switch

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, if-statement

I use else-if statement to check Boolean values and since using the else-if, it causes poor performance.

> From that reason, I am considering to convert the else-if statement into switch statement, so that I'd like to hear your advice to converting it appropriately.

**This is my else-if statement**

```
public class Config_Monday_0 {
private Context mContext;

public Config_Monday_0(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
}

public int monday_0(TextView mon_1, TextView mon_2, TextView mon_3, TextView mon_4, TextView mon_5,
                     TextView mon_6, TextView mon_7, TextView mon_8, TextView mon_9, TextView mon_10,
                     TextView mon_11, TextView mon_12, TextView mon_13, TextView mon_14, TextView mon_15,
                     TextView mon_16, TextView mon_17, TextView mon_18, TextView mon_19, TextView mon_20,
                     TextView mon_21, TextView mon_22, TextView mon_23, TextView mon_24){

    Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0 schedule_boolean_monday0 = new Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0(mContext);
    DatabaseTimetable databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);

    int start_time;
    int end_time;

    //Database 0 AM is not used
    if (!schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_1() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_2() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_3() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_4() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_5() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_6() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_7()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_8() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_9() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_10() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_11() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_12() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_13() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_14() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_15() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_16() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_17()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_18() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_19() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_20() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_21() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_22() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_23() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_24()){
        return 0;
    }
    //0 am - 1 hr.
    else if (schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_1() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_2() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_3() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_4() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_5() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_6() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_7()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_8() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_9() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_10() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_11() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_12() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_13() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_14() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_15() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_16() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_17()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_18() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_19() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_20() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_21() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_22() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_23() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_24()){
        start_time = 0;
        end_time = 1;
        schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_1();
        mon_1.setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start_time, end_time));
        mon_1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        mon_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        return 1;
    }
    //0 am - 2 hr.
    else if (!schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_1() && schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_2() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_3() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_4() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_5() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_6() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_7()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_8() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_9() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_10() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_11() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_12() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_13() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_14() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_15() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_16() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_17()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_18() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_19() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_20() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_21() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_22() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_23() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_24()){
        start_time = 0;
        end_time = 2;
        schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_2();
        mon_1.setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start_time, end_time));
        mon_1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        mon_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        mon_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        return 2;
    }
    //0 am - 3 hr.
    else if (!schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_1() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_2() && schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_3() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_4() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_5() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_6() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_7()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_8() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_9() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_10() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_11() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_12() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_13() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_14() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_15() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_16() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_17()&& !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_18() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_19() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_20() &&
            !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_21() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_22() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_23() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_24()){
        start_time = 0;
        end_time = 3;
        schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_3();
        mon_1.setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start_time, end_time));
        mon_1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        mon_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        mon_2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        mon_3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start_time, end_time)));
        return 3;
    }

    return 99;
    }
}
```

> **This is a class that indicates Boolean variables**

```
public class Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0 {

    private Context mContext;
    private DatabaseTimetable databaseTimetable;

    public Schedule_Boolean_Monday_0(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_1(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,1);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_2(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,2);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_3(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,3);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_4(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,4);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_5(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,5);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_6(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,6);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_7(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,7);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_8(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,8);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_9(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,9);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_10(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,10);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_11(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,11);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_12(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,12);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_13(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,13);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_14(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,14);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_15(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,15);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_16(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,16);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_17(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,17);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_18(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,18);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_19(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,19);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_20(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,20);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_21(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,21);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_22(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,22);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_23(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,23);
        return !result.equals("");
    }

    public Boolean Monday_0_24(){
        databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
        String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,0);
        return !result.equals("");
    }
}
```

> There are 24 Boolean variables in each if/else-if arguments. I thought converting to switch methods might lead better performance for my app and if you have any ideas, I'd like to hear your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the `if` statement, `if` statements are as efficient as they can get. Your problem is accessing the database for every variable access, and this is what you should deal with.

If I were you, I'd read all boolean variables once and then used those values to implement whatever logic you're trying to implement. The main point being, `READ ONCE AND CACHE ALL YOU CAN`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the core principles of writing good code is *avoiding repetition*. In your case, I think trying to adhere to this principle might help.

To expand on Lenik's answer, I think you would be best to first enclose your entire `if` statement in a check that first checks `Monday_0_4` through `Monday_0_24`. Something like this:

```
if( !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_4() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_5() &&  
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_6() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_7()&& 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_8() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_9() && 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_10() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_11() && 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_12() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_13() && 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_14() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_15() && 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_16() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_17()&& 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_18() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_19() && 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_20() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_21() && 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_22() && !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_23() && 
    !schedule_boolean_monday0.Monday_0_24() ) {
    //your existing if statement here, but with the checks for Monday_0_4 through Monday_0_24 removed from each one
}
```

Secondly, just for the sake of nicer code, and bearing in mind I might not fully understand your code, I think you might be best redesigning your database check to the following:

```
public Boolean Monday_0(int hour){
    databaseTimetable = new DatabaseTimetable(mContext);
    String result = databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(0,hour);
    return !result.equals("");
}
```

You could also further simplify your code by:

- Putting one return value `outside` your if statements, returning `end_time`. `end_time` should be initialised to -1, which would double as the "error" return value (instead of 99).
- Moving these outside the if too, because they're called no matter which condition is true: (you'd need another nested if to make sure it's not called when Monday_0_1 is false)

```
mon_1.setText(databaseTimetable.Monday_Title(start_time, end_time));
mon_1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_Color(start_time, end_time)));
mon_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(databaseTimetable.Monday_Text_BG_Color(start_time, end_time)));
```

- Performing your checks with a `for` loop, using the improved database check I mentioned earlier

Hope this helps!